# Syncing Multiple Motor Drivers

Tags: microcontroller, control-system, motor-controller, brushed-dc-motor

I have put together a 4-axis robot operated by brushed DC motors for a haptic feedback system. Unfortunately I am not well versed in robotic control systems so would really appreciate any advice you guys could offer.

My issue is that robot is meant to operate with positional control at sub <1mm accuracy (this is considerably larger than quantisation error of my encoders ~0.1mm) and I do not know how to sync the robot axes together - some of the 4 axis controllers cost upwards of £1000 so are completely unrealistic. So my current plan is to use two [Roboclaw 2x15A](https://www.pololu.com/product/3285)  controllers to operate 2 axes each. Then control both of these off of an arduino or something similar.

Will a cheap microcontroller, like an arduino, be able to operate at a high enough frequency to control the two drivers quickly enough for accurate positional control? Also if anyone could guide me to some literature on where to understand the theory behind controlling motor axes quasi-simulataneously that would be greatly appreciated - google has only provided vague solutions.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

This depends a lot on the interfaces provided by Roboclaw. Best bet is probably step/dir driven from some controller that can calculate synchronous movements. If this is not supported I would look at implementing a ROS bridge for UART communication.

Due to cost of ready made solution I'm trying to implement such synchronized control with CAN and CANOpen - basically position interpolation + buffering + SYNC message to start all axes at the same time. More details available in this paper

https://www.servo2go.com/support/downloads/CoordinatedMulti-AxisMotionControlviaCANbus.pdf

Project is https://distrap.org/ (early development)